# Perfomance and Out Of Memory Error while excepting Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, hadoop, spring-batch

I have a to design a solution to have Spring batch reader to read millions of dataset from Hadoop System, now if the job reads a huge size csv file and process in chunks, there are chances to face OutOfMemory Error, how we can address this situation ?

Comment: Hi, please add more detail about what you want and a code example, stacktrace when getting OutOfMemory if that is the case. your question is very generic.

Comment: Hi Debapiya! If you have a specific question more related to coding, please improve the question as suggested by Jonathan. If you want to keep the question very generic, you might want to take a look at other SO forums. Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is a better place for your question.

Comment: You can go with smaller chunk size or reduce the number of threads